# Error getting local git to new github repository

Tags: git, github

-- EDIT --
I ended up copying all files to another folder an pushed from there. Without the commit history. :(

Thanks for responding tho.

-- /EDIT --

I'm new to git.
For my html5 app I used aptana's html5 boilerplate which installs a git repository for you. Nice.
Now, after working on my app for a few weeks, I want to push it to github. I created a new repository there.

Now when I try to push to github from shell or tortoisegit I run into errors after all files are uploaded:

```
$ git push -u origin master
...
remote: error: unable to find b4587434...<snip>...c701 (probably a checksum)
remote: fatal: objet of unexpected type
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit 
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git'
```

I have been looking all around for a solution, but haven't been able to find something yet. Some actions I tried that didn't help:

- I have renamed origin to something else.
- I've created another repository on github.
- "git status" confirms that I have nothing to commit.

Please help, It's really frustrating that git costs so much time to figure out for something that should be simple. :(

Comment: What does `git fsck --full` say?

Comment: Checking objects directories: 100%
Checking objects: 100%

Comment: I had the same issue on a centos 7. My git version was 1.8, after updating git to 2.17 the error disapeared.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to mirror Twbs bootstrap, but got an error like this and my problem was that I cloned the repo with `--depth=1`. I re-cloned the repo without the `--depth=` argument and everything worked perfectly using these steps:

1. `git clone --bare https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git`
2. `cd bootstrap.git`
3. `git push --mirror git@github.com:yourusername/your-repo-name.git`
4. `cd ../ && rm -rf bootstrap.git`
5. `git clone git@github.com:yourusername/your-repo-name.git`
6. `cd your-repo-name`
7. `git remote add twbs https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git`

Now you can push to your own version of the repo with `git push origin master` and if you'd like to pull changes from the original repo you can simple do `git pull twbs master`.

More info available @ https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

Answer (score 0):

So one thing you could try is:

1. Go-to github.com/THE_REPO_YOU_MADE
2. Copy the SSH url that is at the top of your repo
3. Remove any old origin remotes

   ```
   git remote
   git remote rm origin
   ```
4. Create a github remote named "origin"(or whatever name you want)

   ```
   git remote add origin git@github.com:USER_NAME/REPO_NAME.git
   ```
5. Push your files to the remote you just added

   ```
   git push remote origin master
   ```

these step are assuming that you have done:

```
git init # creates a local repo
git add . # adds all files in the current directory
git commit -m "init commit" #commits your init
```

I know these are very basic steps and may not answer your error your receiving but these steps

one other thing to try is check to see if you have a repo inside of a repo.
this is something that my students run into sometimes. it will cause some errors when tying to push and also with permissions

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that and got the same result unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 0):

Note: at least with git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014), the error message could be more specific.

See [commit 77583e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77583e7739c76f623f49681c9ee4d10a313fe786) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff):

#### `index-pack`: distinguish missing objects from type errors

> When we fetch a pack that does not contain an object we expected to receive, we get an error like:

```
$ git init --bare tmp.git && cd tmp.git
$ git fetch ../parent.git
[...]
error: Could not read 964953ec7bcc0245cb1d0db4095455edd21a2f2e
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit b8247b40caf6704fe52736cdece6d6aae87471aa
error: ../parent.git did not send all necessary objects
```

> This comes from the `check_everything_connected rev-list`. If we try cloning the same repo (rather than a `fetch`), we end up using `index-pack`'s `--check-self-contained-and-connected` option instead, which produces output like:

```
$ git clone --no-local --bare parent.git tmp.git
[...]
fatal: object of unexpected type
fatal: index-pack failed
```

> Not only is the sha1 missing, but it's a misleading message.
>   There's no type problem, but rather a missing object problem; we don't notice the difference because we simply compare `OBJ_BAD != OBJ_BLOB`.
>   Let's provide a different message for this case:

```
$ git clone --no-local --bare parent.git tmp.git
fatal: did not receive expected object 6b00a8c61ed379d5f925a72c1987c9c52129d364
fatal: index-pack failed
```

> While we're at it, let's also improve a true type mismatch error to look like

```
fatal: object 6b00a8c61ed379d5f925a72c1987c9c52129d364: expected type blob, got tree
```

Comment: Hi, did you get the right solution?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @user1938143 I have no direct solution, just a better diagnostic through a more precise error message.